# Intellij git branches - group them into folders

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-branch, git-flow, intellij-plugin

I'm using [gitflow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) for my project.
I decided not to squash feature commit for the moment because it's an experimental project and I want fine grane control over modification. Hence I have many branches named `feature/<some_feature_name>`.

The default behavior of the "Branches..." view of IDEA is to flatten them out displaying a long list that looks like:

```
├─ master/
├─ develop/
├─ feature/f1
├─ feature/f2
├─ feature/f3
├─ [...]
├─ hotfix/h1
├─ hotfix/h2
└─ [...]
```

Many git GUIs graphically groups them into "folders", something like:

```
├─ master/
├─ develop/
├─ feature/  
│   ├─ f1
│   ├─ f2
│   ├─ f3
│   └─ [...]
└─ hotfix/
    ├─ h1
    ├─ h2
    └─ [...]
```

Is there any plugin/setting to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't be support by IntelliJ IDEA.

See:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140691
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127468

**Reason**

IntelliJ IDEA tries to have a consistent UX. One thing you can rely on is that you can start to filter/search in any view by just start typing. This is really easy and helps to create a consistent mouseless experience.

If you want to see all `hotfix` branches, just type `hotfix`!

**In short**: A flattened tree is easier to filter and search if you follow the mouseless UX matra.

Comment: it has been realized, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127468/Group-branches-by-remote-name-and-by-groups-separated-with-slash